How to Display Total Object Count in Wagtail Snippet ViewSet?
I am currently developing a Wagtail project where I use the ModelAdmin to create custom admin interfaces for my models. When using ModelAdmin, the total object count of a model is displayed below the model name in the list view. However, when I switched to using SnippetViewSet, I lost this functionality.I would like to display the total object count in the list view based on the custom get_queryset method defined in my SnippetViewSet class.
ModelAdmin:

SnippetViewSet:


class ModelBViewSet(SnippetViewSet):
    model = ModelB
    icon = 'folder'
    list_display = ["foo", "bar"]
    menu_name = "Unloaded Objects ModelB"

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = ModelB.objects.filter(foo='foo')
        return qs

    

register_snippet(PidProviderViewSet)

